# Windows 7 hangs at "Starting Windows" screen when dual-booting with Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot, grub

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 in a dual boot configuration.  I have my original Windows 7 installation on my C: drive and the new Ubuntu 14.04 installation in a partition on my d: drive.  GRUB shows my Windows 7 as a boot option, but when I try to boot into Windows 7 it hangs at the "Starting Windows" splash screen.

Unfortunately I didn't find out until after this happened that Ubuntu has had a problem dual booting with Windows for 3 years.  Something in Ubuntu's boot loader destroys what Windows 7 needs to boot.

The hardware is a HP DV7T-6C00 laptop.

I tried boot-repair which didn't work.  I also tried using MS System Restore from the HP recovery disk which didn't work either.

How can I solve this issue and dual-boot Windows 7 with Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm asking if there is a Linux distro that will not cause this problem with dual booting, or if I will find this problem in all current linux distros.  If it's a GRUB problem then all Linux distros will have it.  Dual booting is definitely not working and many others have had this problem.

Comment: Again, all Linux distros with GRUB are *supposed* to run alongside Windows 7 just fine. Your current question would just elicit answers that say "Distro *XYZ* works for me". It should be easy enough for you to try other distros and see if they work. As for your actual issue: We don't even know what the exact problem is or if it's just a matter of reconfiguring/reinstalling GRUB (and whether you've already tried that). Try to ask about how to solve your problem rather than about what you think is the solution. (If you're not interested in futzing around you probably won't solve the issue.)